# Perform network operation to check if user has internet connection with async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, internet-connection

I am getting below exception

> ```
> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
> ```

because I don't use an async task to make the particular network operation. I  have searched for this, but it got me so confused. Could someone make it work with async task and the particular functions?

Below are two functions i use :

1)  **isNetworkAvailable()**

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;

}
```

2)  **hasInternetAccess(Boolean showMessage)**

When i want to display a toast i call this function, setting the parameter to **true**.

```
public boolean hasInternetAccess(Boolean showMessage) {

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)
                    (new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204")
                            .openConnection());
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            urlc.connect();
            return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 204 &&
                    urlc.getContentLength() == 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("connection", "Error checking internet connection", e);
        }
    } else {
        if(showMessage) // If i want to show the toast, it's true
            showAToast("No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); // Just another function to show a toast
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should call the Http services in background

Comment: You need to use aync task for hasInternetAccess() method, as you are accessing internet

Comment: @Vickyexpert do you mean calling hasInternetAccess() in an async task? or inside the function to make it use async task?

Comment: @Nithinlal inside they try/catch?

Comment: I think the reason for the error i, Tony is not calling Http services in background. U can use asyntask or thread for that, its upto u for background calling

Comment: @Nithinlal i know what the problem is, i just don't know how to use async task, i am reading about this but i am confused. Could you use an async task with those two functions? I don't want to sound like i want you just to give me the answer, but it would help me a lot understand how async task works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can use an AsyncTask by creating an inner class which extends AsyncTask.

```
private class NetworkInAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;

    NetworkInAsync(Activity activity) {
        this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
        this.activity = activity;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // Do something with the result here 
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            try {
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)
                (new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204")
                        .openConnection());
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);
                urlc.connect();
                return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 204 &&
                urlc.getContentLength() == 0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.w("connection", "Error checking internet connection", e);
            }
        } else {
            if(showMessage) // If i want to show the toast, it's true
            showAToast("No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); // Just another function to show a toast
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can execute the AsyncTask as follows

```
new NetworkInAsync(this).execute();
```

I would still recommend you go through the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to clarify yourself how AsyncTask works in Android.

Comment: How should i call this? and i want it to return a boolean, should i change something in -> extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>?

Comment: Trying to make it work, give me some time, could i call this line( new NetworkInAsync(this).execute() ) in an "if" statement returning true or false?

Comment: Its an asynctask so you can call it anywhere but it will return the result inside onPostExecute after the operation is completed inside doInBackground

Comment: currently i can't use boolean, it has to be Boolean, and when i change this it gives me "Method does not override method from it's superclass" in onPostExecute

Comment: now it doesn't have an error in async task, but in the line that i call async task which is in an if statement, if ( new NetworkInAsync(this).execute() ) {code} it says required Boolean, found android.os.AsyncTask <java.lang.String, java.lang.Void, java.lang.Boolean>

Comment: See its an an AsyncTask you can't use it like that it will return the Boolean result inside the onPostExecute and you can do your if check there you just call this new NetworkInAsync(this).execute(); where ever you want and use the logic check inside onPostExecute

Comment: You are welcome i am glad i was able to help. Please upvote the answer as well. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The code should work when you call it from `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` method

call `test();`

```
private void test() {
HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)
                    (new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204")
                            .openConnection());

            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            urlc.connect();
}
```

You can check the network connection before making the call, but any how, you should catch the exception in TimeOut exception. So I dont think, that you have any much benifit to check the connectivity before making the call.