# NullPointerException when using interface to transfer the result from AsyncTask to MainActivity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

In my AsyncTask, I have `doInBackground` return an arrayof Movie objects. After searching on how to achieve that, I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a) and implemented the solution suggested by the marked answer. The only difference is that as oppose to running the AsyncTask in my `onCreate` method in the **MainActivity**, I have the AsyncTask running in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method in **MainActivity**.

I was not quite certain solution meant in his implementation of the `processFinish` method, so I implemented mine like so ( in **MainActivity**). The `list_of_movies` variable is a global variable that I intend to pass into a GridView later.

```
@Override
public void processFinish(Movie[] movies){
    for(int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++){
        list_of_movies[i] = movies[i];
    }
}
```

To check that I actually have all the movie objects within `list_of_movies`, I did a quick loop of Log after I execute the AsyncTask in my `onOptionsItemsSelected`

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_popular) {
        FetchMovieTask movieTask = new FetchMovieTask();
        movieTask.delegate = this;
        movieTask.execute("popular");

        for(int i = 0; i < list_of_movies.length; i++){
            Log.v("Loop Logging", list_of_movies[i].getTitle());
        }

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Which returns me a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

I've tried the following

1) I thought maybe I was not allow to call this operation within `onOptionsItemSelected`, so I tried the same operation in `onCreate` instead. Also the same error

2) I simply set `list_of_movies = movies` in the `processFinish` method, but that does not work either

What am I doing wrong here?

I thought maybe it's because I added the `public` to the `processFinish` method, but without `public` Android Studio would not let me compile due to some clashing issues. Another theory is that `list_of_movies` is pointing at nothing, but I thought that's the whole point of using interfaces to transfer the Movie[].

Sorry if I'm simply misunderstanding some fundamental concepts of Android, just started learning a few weeks ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what an AsyncTask is doing.

It is doing operations in the background, and when it is **completed**, goes to `processFinish` of the `delegate` interface. Meanwhile, all code after the `execute` method continues to run.

Therefore, would you be surprised if this caused an error? The `list_of_movies` variable contains no data yet.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list_of_movies.length; i++){
    Log.v("Loop Logging", list_of_movies[i].getTitle());
}

FetchMovieTask movieTask = new FetchMovieTask();
movieTask.delegate = this;
movieTask.execute("popular");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What is the correct way of transferring the data from `onPostExecute` to `list_of_movies` ?

Comment: You are already doing that correctly. You just cannot log the data before the AsyncTask has finished.

Answer (score 0):

The list that you are returning from doInBackground is passed to the onPostExecute interface method. So you can do something like below inside you AsyncTask class.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Movie[] movies) {
    for(int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++){
    list_of_movies[i] = movies[i];
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39306304/3426524) is another solution/answer that i gave which should give you a much better idea on how does Asynctask works in android.